# openUrl command works in Obj-C but not Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, nsworkspace

Our codebase is still very much a hybrid codebase, but I've been trying to do more work in Swift. Unfortunately I'm running into a weird situation where a command that works fine in Obj-C absolutely refuses to run in Swift.

I'm trying to send a file from one of our desktop products to another of our products. All of the URL schemes are set up correctly. This command in Obj-C works perfectly:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ourotherapp://v1/import?filePath=/Users/gi.joe/Documents/test.wav"]];
```

However, in trying to use the Swift version, this one absolutely refuses to execute. No exception, no clue, no nothing:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(fileURLWithPath: "ourotherapp://v1/import?filePath=/Users/gi.joe/Documents/test.wav"))
```

Is there some difference in the way `NSWorkspace` works in Swift as opposed to Obj-C? I've looked over the Apple docs but maybe I missed something?

Comment: I think that `URL(fileURLWithPath:)` counterpart in ObjC is `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]` and not `[NSURL URLWithString:]`, so technically those two calls are not equivalent

Comment: Wowwwwww. I looked at these so many times my eyes were blurry and I STILL did not catch that. That's the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you tried two different calls in Obj C and Swift.

I haven't tried the below code, maybe this example helps you:

```
if let checkURL = NSURL(string: "https://google.com") {
    if NSWorkspace.shared().open(checkURL as URL) {
        print("URL Successfully Opened")
    }
} else {
    print("Invalid URL")
}
```

Comment: After much examination, it appears you are correct! They are indeed two different calls. And I feel like an idiot.

Comment: great you got a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "someURL") else { return }
UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```

Comment: Sorry - I specified in the tag but it looks like I forgot to mention in the body of the question, this is macOS, not iOS. Turns out the concept is right, though. I was using the wrong parameter - it should have been `string`, not `fileURLWithPath`.